# How to limit access to active admin to admin users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I want that only my users who have their attribute `is_admin` set to true to be able to access my active admin backend

*how should I do this?*

"Normal" users should only be able to login to the site, not to active admin.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

In `config/initializers/active_admin.rb` you have such config:

```
config.authentication_method = :authenticate_admin_user!
```

so if you create a method named authenticate_admin_user! in the ApplicationController, then ActiveAdmin will check if the user can go to the admin pages or not. Like this:

```
# restrict access to admin module for non-admin users
def authenticate_admin_user!
  raise SecurityError unless current_user.try(:admin?)
end
```

and rescue from that exception in ApplicationController (or you can actually redirect inside the `authenticate_admin_user!` method)

```
rescue_from SecurityError do |exception|
  redirect_to root_url
end
```

And one more small thing, if you don't have admin_users, then it would be nice to change this line in `config/initializers/active_admin.rb`:

```
config.current_user_method = :current_user
```

And with devise you might want to make the default path different for admin/non-admin users, so you can define `after_sign_in_path_for` method in the controller

```
# path for redirection after user sign_in, depending on user role
def after_sign_in_path_for(user)
  user.admin? ? admin_dashboard_path : root_path 
end
```

Comment: This seems like a good solution, bu current_user seems unavailable within the ApplicationController... Can't I put it somewhere else?

Comment: mm controller is actually the place where it is used the most. So what problem do you have, it returns nil or NoMethodError?

Comment: It returns nil; `undefined method 'admin?' for nil:NilClass`. I DID define the .admin? method, so that's not it. I found several cases of current_user not being available in the ApplicationControlller, it seems you're not supposed to acces it from there.

Comment: D'oh, obviously when not logged in, no active_user is present xD So authenticate_admin_user should read `!current_user.nil? and current_user.admin?`. Getting there now.

Comment: yep, you are right. And tried the code, returning true/false did not work for me, so changed it to the exceptions system (edited the answer for both this issue and current_user is nil case)

Comment: Also, the custom authentication method shouldn't return true or false, but handle the redirection.

Comment: Your answer is very good, thanks a lot! I really like the SecurityError handling way of doing this!

Answer (score 0):

For "Normal" users you should write separate logic to login to the site or maybe I did not understand why you want to allow users to login through the active admin.
Active admin using [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise), just create another model called [User](http://railscasts.com/episodes/209-introducing-devise).

Comment: No that's not what I want to do, since admin users should be able to use the front part of the site too. I believe it's good practice to have only one user model.